# c# Web API 500 error from method after adding authentication

Tags: c#, swagger

I have been trying to fix this all day. I am making a test API to practice my development. I tried adding a bearer authentication error and now none of the methods work.

```
namespace WebApiTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
            });
            // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
                {
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
                    Scheme = "Bearer",
                    BearerFormat = "JWT",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "JWT Authorization header. \r\n\r\n Enter the token in the text input below."
                });
                c.OperationFilter<AddAuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
        {
            try
            {
                app.UseSwagger();

                app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
                {
                    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Web API Test");
                });

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }

                app.UseHttpsRedirection();

                app.UseRouting();

                app.UseAuthorization();

                app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while configuring the application.");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
    public class AddAuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
        {
            var authAttributes = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .Union(context.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>();

            if (authAttributes.Any())
            {
                operation.Security = new List<OpenApiSecurityRequirement>
            {
                new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference { Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id = "Bearer" },
                        },
                        new string[] {}
                    }
                }
            };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace AzureWebApiTest.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MainController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly LoginRequest loginInformation = new LoginRequest("username", "password");

        [HttpPost("GetToken")]
        public IActionResult GetToken([FromBody] LoginRequest loginRequest)
        {
            if (loginRequest == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Bad Login Request");
            }

            if (loginRequest.Equals(loginInformation))
            {
                var token = GenerateBearerToken(loginRequest);
                return Ok(new { token });
            }
            else
            {
                return Unauthorized("Incorrect Login Information");
            }
        }

        [HttpGet("GetHello")]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
        public IActionResult GetHello([FromQuery] string name)
        {
            try
            {
                var token = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("secretKey"))
                };
                var claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out var securityToken);

                return Ok("Hello " + name);
            }
            catch (SecurityTokenExpiredException)
            {
                return Unauthorized("Token has expired.");
            }
            catch (SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException)
            {
                return Unauthorized("Invalid token signature.");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Unauthorized("Invalid token.");
            }
        }

        private string GenerateBearerToken(LoginRequest loginRequest)
        {
            if (ValidateCredentials(loginRequest))
            {
                var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("secretKey");
                var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                {
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                };
                var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
                return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private bool ValidateCredentials(LoginRequest loginRequest)
        {
            if(loginRequest.Equals(loginInformation))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try the method in swagger, I am getting the response:

[image: Response]

I've tried getting ChatGPT to fix it but I'm getting nowhere and it's going in circles. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit:
The Validate function returns false at the end, I changed it for testing purposes. Edited back.

Comment: We may be able to help you fix the error once you tell us what it is.. you'll have to do some debugging and tell us what is causing the error.

Comment: 500 is an internal server error/exception, most likely an unhandled exception. You need to debug your server side code to figure out what the exception / error is, then you can try to figure out why it occurs and how to fix it.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can find these errors? So far, all I get from Azure is:

<div class="content-container"><fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4>This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.<p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=500,0,0x00000000,14393">View more information &raquo;</a></p><p>Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:</p>

In my Application Logs.

Comment: You'll need to get the server logs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs

Comment: From my Web Server Logs:

2023-01-17 15:50:57 AZUREWEBAPITEST POST /api/Main/GetToken X-ARR-LOG-ID=3b4d62bc-b327-411f-ba78-35c7315fac49 443 - myIP Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/108.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/108.0.1462.54 ARRAffinity=22a7daa836b64a8ce56c907737553d08297ff2e76cd06a1f52c29956b9a85c17;+ARRAffinitySameSite=22a7daa836b64a8ce56c907737553d08297ff2e76cd06a1f52c29956b9a85c17 mywebsite mywebsite 500 0 0 363 1699 218

Is this of any help?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get authorization to work, but you lack a few things.

Authentication

```
services.AddAuthentication(..options..).AddJwtBearer(..options..)
```

You need to add authentication to the pipeline, by adding UseAuthentication() before UseAuthorization(), like:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

You need to add / register the authorization service using

```
services.AddAuthorization(..options..);
```